# Can you stop your PHP Code from being delivered to your Client just like JavaEE and .NET?

Tags: java, php, .net

Can you stop your PHP Code from being  delivered to  your Client just like JavaEE and .NET?
As in JavaEE we can compile all our classes into .class extensions and all .jsp pages calling backend (business logic) beans can access those pages while no person can acccess or alter it.

Similarly in .Net we can compile our whole ASP.net website (Business Logic) classes into .dll
files and again no one can access our code.although we have to ensure Obfuscation process also in both cases.

But what to do in the case of PHP?

Can anyone tell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [obfuscate PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=protect+php+code) and you can put it into [executable Phar archives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php), but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't delivered to the 'client' (meaning the computer that's displaying the webpage).  It's 'transformed' into HTML on the server (this is a very simple explanation).

If by client you mean, "Someone you're producing a product for that you don't want to see the code": The simple answer is, don't turn over the website to anyone else.

Of course, at that point is PHP really your best option?

Comment: I know this , but client have access to server he can get our code altered and can hand it over to other client with minimum alterations. Gordon  give the correct solution i think.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on who your clients are (i.e. if they can afford it), you can possibly use Zend Guard
http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/
which brings additional benefit of increasing performance a bit.